# Getting today's record in MySQL ignoring time and hour

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select the current records on daily basis but the timestamp is giving problems with my query.

```
SELECT * FROM `collections` WHERE rdate_collect = curdate()
```

In the database I have the record to be `2015-12-08 15:30:12`. Is there a way i can format the date so that it only return the date alone but with the time too, so it can only return the current day's records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want all the records for the current date where the values are stored as `2015-12-08 15:30:12` you can easily use `date()` function over the column in the select something as

`where date(rdate_collect) = curdate()`

The disadvantage is it will never use index even if the column is indexed and when you have large amount of data it would create an issue since the query will be slow.

So you can format the query as

```
where 
rdate_collect >= concat(curdate(),' ','00:00:00')
and rdate_collect <= concat(curdate(),' ','23:59:59')
```

Here is a live example, I have a `login_audit` table and it has a column `last_login(datetime)` and its indexed.

So lets see step by step

```
mysql> select count(*) from login_audit ;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  5188680 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have large number of records into the table

Now lets use date() function and see what it shows in explain plan

```
mysql> explain select count(*) from login_audit where date(last_login) = curdate() ;
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+----------------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type  | possible_keys | key            | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+----------------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | login_audit | index | NULL          | last_login_idx | 5       | NULL | 5188680 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+----------------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
```

From the explain plan looks like mysql may scan the entire table and it will be a slow query.

Now change the query and see

```
mysql> explain select count(*) from login_audit where last_login >= concat(curdate(),' ','00:00:00') and last_login <= concat(curdate(),' ','23:59:59') ;
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+----------------+----------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type  | possible_keys  | key            | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+----------------+----------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | login_audit | range | last_login_idx | last_login_idx | 5       | NULL |    1 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+----------------+----------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
```

So yes this time its better

And here is the time difference in the query

```
mysql> select count(*) from login_audit where date(last_login) = curdate() ;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.92 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from login_audit where last_login >= concat(curdate(),' ','00:00:00') and last_login <= concat(curdate(),' ','23:59:59') ;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: what if the time is 23:59:59.999 ? :) recently mysql added support for fractional seconds in datetime values

Comment: now i'm trying to get the results with date variables the user will submit. How do i format the date field to pick up the variable the user sends "WHERE rdate_collect BETWEEN rdate1 AND rdate2"

Comment: Yes you can do that way and better use `>= and <=` instead of between.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM `collections` WHERE date(rdate_collect) = curdate();
```

Comment: curdate() already returns just the date.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [date()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function so you query could look like:

```
SELECT * FROM `collections` WHERE date(rdate_collect) = curdate()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have optimal performances with this solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM `collections`
WHERE
  rdate_collect >= curdate() AND rdate_collect < curdate() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

this will just make use of date functions, no string conversions, and will use an index if present on rdate_collect.